# How to "rotate" data in Excel (Complicated transpose)

Tags: excel

Say I have the information:

```
NAME  Class1 Class2 Class3
NAME2 Class2 Class3 Class4
```

I want to turn this into:

```
NAME  Class1
NAME  Class2
NAME  Class3
NAME2  Class2
NAME2  Class3
NAME2  Class4
```

I'd use Paste > Transpose, except I have 550 names with up to 10 classes each. So I'd have to copy, insert 10 blank rows, paste > transpose and then trim blank rows 500 times.

Is there are better way?

Comment: How comfortable are you with `vba`? you could record a macro doing one of the `paste>transpose` functions, then adapt it to use a `loop` to do the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data like this in *Sheet1*

[image]

Running this macro:

```
Sub ReOrganize()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim M As Long, v As String

    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    k = 1
    N = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        v = Cells(i, 1).Value
        M = Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For j = 2 To M
            sh2.Cells(k, 1) = v
            sh2.Cells(k, 2) = sh1.Cells(i, j)
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Will produce this in *Sheet2*

[image]

Comment: Indeed, and I found a similar answer after googling a little more, that I adapted. The actual code I used I'll post as an alternate answer

Answer (score 1):

The above answer looks like a variant of the one I ended up finding at https://superuser.com/questions/633124/how-do-i-split-one-row-into-multiple-rows-with-excel

The code itself that I used from that page is:

```
Sub NewLayout()
    For i = 2 To Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        For j = 0 To 2
        If Cells(i, 3 + j) <> vbNullString Then
            intCount = intCount + 1
            Cells(i, 1).Copy Destination:=Cells(intCount, 10)
            Cells(i, 2).Copy Destination:=Cells(intCount, 11)
            Cells(i, 3 + j).Copy Destination:=Cells(intCount, 12)
        End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Which instead of pasting into a new sheet like the above answer, pastes into columns 10-12 of the same sheet.